# Get Specific Version in TFS 2012 does not show the conflicts

Tags: tfs, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer-everywhere

I use eclipse TFS plugin to connect to TFS servers. We used to use TFS 2010. When doing get specific version, the TFS gets all the latest version of the file, and if there were any conflicts with the local file, it showed the list of conflicts. We can edit the conflicts. But after we upgraded to TFS 2012, get Specific version gets the latest version, it doesn't show any conflicts. Is there any config we need to make to show the conflicts? I am not doing a merge it only a get operation.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2012 (and newer) attempt to automerge any changes by default, rather than making you explicitly deal with the conflict resolution and manually attempt the automerge.  This is generally in line with the default options of other version control tools, however you can disable this if you do not like it.

This setting is in the Eclipse Preferences, in Team > Team Foundation Server > Source Control:

> Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated.

[image]